# Finding the depth of a json in PHP

Tags: php, json

In the html page I can get any one of the below mentioned jsons, now in order to know which json is recieved I need to check the depths of these json objects. can somebody suggest a way to get the depth of json object in PHP.

The two formats of the json are mentioned below:

```
{
  "Category": {
    "name" : "Camera",
    "productDetails" : {
      "imageUrl" : "/assets/images/product1.png",
      "productName" : "GH700 Digital Camera",
      "originalPrice" : 20000,
      "discountPrice" : 16000,
      "discount" : 20
     }
}
```

and

```
{
  "city" : {
    "cityname": "ABC",
    "Category": {
      "name" : "Camera",
      "productDetails" : {
        "imageUrl" : "/assets/images/product1.png",
        "productName" : "GH700 Digital Camera",
        "originalPrice" : 20000,
        "discountPrice" : 16000,
        "discount" : 20
       }
  }
}
```

Comment: count(json_decode(yourjson))

Comment: there are better ways to check which kind of JSON object you received: has the first level a key named "city"? if true, then it's the second type, else it's the first type.

Answer (score 3):

**Introduction**

Want to imagine your json looks like this

```
$jsonA = '{
  "Category": {
    "name" : "Camera",
    "productDetails" : {
      "imageUrl" : "/assets/images/product1.png",
      "productName" : "GH700 Digital Camera",
      "originalPrice" : 20000,
      "discountPrice" : 16000,
      "discount" : 20
     }
}';



$jsonB = '{
  "city" : {
    "cityname": "ABC",
    "Category": {
      "name" : "Camera",
      "productDetails" : {
        "imageUrl" : "/assets/images/product1.png",
        "productName" : "GH700 Digital Camera",
        "originalPrice" : 20000,
        "discountPrice" : 16000,
        "discount" : 20
       }
  }
';
```

**Question 1**

`now in order to know which json is recieved I need to check the depths of these json objects.`

**Answer 1**

You do not need the depth to know which `json` it all you need to do is use the first key such as `city` or `category`

Example

```
$json = json_decode($unknown);
if (isset($json->city)) {
    // this is $jsonB
} else if (isset($json->Category)) {
    // this is $jsonA
}
```

**Question 2**
`can somebody suggest a way to get the depth of json object in PHP`

```
echo getDepth(json_decode($jsonA, true)), PHP_EOL; // returns 2
echo getDepth(json_decode($jsonB, true)), PHP_EOL; // returns 3
```

Function Used

```
function getDepth(array $arr) {
    $it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr));
    $depth = 0;
    foreach ( $it as $v ) {
        $it->getDepth() > $depth and $depth = $it->getDepth();
    }
    return $depth;
}
```